# How to pass dynamic `groupID` from one js file to another js file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have attached my code for reference, In that I want to pass dynamic **groupID** from `teamgroupapi.js` to `teamCategoryApi.js`

Code is working fine when I try to pass manually groupID from `ApiCategory.js` file.

File name `teamgroupapi.js`

```
import { getGeneratedApi } from '@test/bender-executor-simple-api-generator';
import ApiGroup from '../_support/ApiGroup.js';


const request = require('supertest');
const fs = require('fs');
const assert = require('assert')
const chakram = require ('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;

const swaggerPath = process.env.BENDER_SWAGGER_PATH || 'https://api-s10938402.cc-staging.test.com/documentation/api.yaml';
const token = process.env.BENDER_LOGIN_TOKEN || 'JTFihw2GJbJ87duTihoGW3vBi8MErxTbBJsD4dw6k5MsPmfI0J8lsf9-mRFXufFYYMzEVcEdK8kXEi3EVkojHQ';
console.log(`login token is ${token}`);
const apiUrl = 'https://' + (process.env.CC_URL_API || 'api-s10938402.cc-staging.test.com');

const readJsonTestFile = (testfilename) =>  {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testfilename, 'utf8'));
};


describe('Create Group all api generated', () => {

  let api;
  let groupID;
  let apiGroup;
  const groupName = "Test_" + new Date().getTime();
  const groupName_rename = "Rename_" + new Date().getTime();

  //const groupJson = { "name": groupName };
  //const grouprenameJson = { "name": groupName_rename };

  beforeAll(async () => {
      api = await getGeneratedApi(apiUrl, token, swaggerPath);
      console.log(api);
      apiGroup = new ApiGroup();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
   //  TODO setup.cleanupDb();
   //  await setup.gateway();
  });
  //Create Group API
  test('Create Group', async() => {
    try
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Create Group");
      //const payload = readJsonTestFile('e2e/example.json');
      const groupJson = apiGroup.generateCreateGroupJsonObject(groupName);
      const createGroup = await api.postTeamGroups(groupJson);
      //const listofGroups = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createGroup));
      //expect(result.response.statusCode).toBe(201);
      expect(createGroup).to.have.status(201);
      console.log("Create group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to create group");
      throw e;
    }
  });
  //Get Group API
  test('Get Group API', async() => {
    try
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Get Created Group");
      let foundIndex = -1;
      console.log("Running get group and attempting to get ::: " + groupName);
      //Check if previously created Group exists using the GET Group API
      //Check the response payload and loop through the response to find the workspace that was created earlier
      const getGroup = await api.getTeamGroups(false,false);
      //const listofGroups = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getGroup));
      //console.log("list of groups" + getGroup.body.length);
      expect(getGroup).to.have.status(200);
        for(var i = 0; i < getGroup.body.length;i++){
            if((getGroup.body[i].name == groupName) && (getGroup.body[i].id != '') ) {
                 foundIndex = i;
                 break;
             }
        }
      groupID = getGroup.body[i].id;
      console.log("Group ID ---->>>>" + getGroup.body[i].id);
      console.log("Group Name ---->>>>" + getGroup.body[i].name);
      expect(foundIndex).to.be.above(-1);
      console.log("Get group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to get group");
      throw e;     
    }
  });
  // Rename Group API
    test.skip('Rename Group API with Group ID', async()=> {
    try 
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Rename already created group");
      const groupJson = apiGroup.generateCreateGroupJsonObject(groupName_rename);
      const apigroup = await api.postTeamGroupsWithGroupID(groupID,groupJson);
      expect(apigroup).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Rename group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to rename group");
      throw e;     
    }
  });
  //Delete Group API
  test.skip('Delete Group API', async()=> {
    try 
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Delete Created Group");
      console.log("Running delete group and attemptin to delete ::: " + groupID);

      const apigroup = await api.deleteTeamGroupsWithGroupID(groupID);

      expect(apigroup).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Delete group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to delete group");
      throw e;     
    }
  });
});
```

Separate Json Functions for `teamgroupapi.js` File name `ApiGroup.js`

```
class ApiGroup {

  constructor()
  {
    //super();
  }

generateCreateGroupJsonObject(groupName)  {

    return {
      "name": groupName 
    }
  }
} 

module.exports = ApiGroup;
```

File name `teamCategoryApi.js`

```
import { getGeneratedApi } from '@test/bender-executor-simple-api-generator';
import ApiCategory from '../_support/ApiCategory.js';
import teamgroupapi from './teamgroupapi.js';

const request = require('supertest');
const fs = require('fs');
const assert = require('assert')
const chakram = require ('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;

const swaggerPath = process.env.BENDER_SWAGGER_PATH || 'https://api-s10938402.cc-staging.test.com/documentation/api.yaml';
const token = process.env.BENDER_LOGIN_TOKEN || 'JTFihw2GJbJ87duTihoGW3vBi8MErxTbBJsD4dw6k5MsPmfI0J8lsf9-mRFXufFYYMzEVcEdK8kXEi3EVkojHQ';
console.log(`login token is ${token}`);
const apiUrl = 'https://' + (process.env.CC_URL_API || 'api-s10938402.cc-staging.test.com');

const readJsonTestFile = (testfilename) =>  {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testfilename, 'utf8'));
};

describe('Create category all api generated', () => {

  let api;
  let categoryID;
  let apiCategory;
  let groupID;
  //let teamGroup;
  const categoryName = "Test_" + new Date().getTime();
  const categoryName_rename = "Rename_" + new Date().getTime();
  //const categoryrenameJson = { "name": categoryName_rename };

  beforeAll(async () => {
      api = await getGeneratedApi(apiUrl, token, swaggerPath);
      console.log(api);
      apiCategory = new ApiCategory();
      //teamGroup = new teamgroupapi();
      //console.log(api);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
   //   TODO setup.cleanupDb();
   //   await setup.gateway();
  });

  //Create Category API
  test('Create Category', async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(20000);
    try {
      console.log("Create Category");
      /*const groupID = teamGroupApi.groupID;
      let api = teamGroupApi.api;*/
      /*groupID = teamgroupapi.groupID;
      console.log(groupID);*/

      const categoryJson = apiCategory.generateCreateCategoryJsonObject(categoryName,groupID);
      //const categoryJson = { "name": categoryName, "groupId": groupID, "parent": 0 };
      const createCategory = await api.postTeamCategories(categoryJson);
      //const listofCategories = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createCategory));
      //expect(result.response.statusCode).toBe(201);
      expect(createCategory).to.have.status(201);
      console.log("Create category successfully executed");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      console.log("Failed to create category");
      throw e;
    }
  });

  //Get Category API
  test.skip('Get Category API', async() => {
    jest.setTimeout(20000);
    try {
      console.log("Get Created Category");
      let foundIndex = -1;
      //const categoryName = "Test_" + new Date().getTime();
      console.log("Running get category and attempting to get ::: " + categoryName);
      //Check if previously created Group exists using the GET Group API
      //Check the response payload and loop through the response to find the workspace that was created earlier
            //let api = teamGroupApi.api;

      const getCategory = await api.getTeamCategories();
      //const listofCategories = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(apicategory));
      //console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
      //console.log("list of category" + apicategory.body.length);
      expect(getCategory).to.have.status(200);
        for(var i = 0; i < getCategory.body.length;i++){
            if((getCategory.body[i].name == categoryName) && (getCategory.body[i].id != '') ) {
                 foundIndex = i;
                 break;
             }
        }
      categoryID = getCategory.body[i].id;
      console.log("Category Name ---->>>>" + getCategory.body[i].id);
      console.log("Category Name ---->>>>" + getCategory.body[i].name);
      expect(foundIndex).to.be.above(-1);
      console.log("Get Category successfully executed");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      console.log("Failed to get category");
      throw e;
    }
  });

  //Rename Category API
  test.skip('Rename Category API with categoryID', async()=> {
      jest.setTimeout(20000);
      try {
      console.log("Rename already created category");

      const renameCategoryJson = apiCategory.renameCreateCategoryJsonObject(categoryName_rename);

      //const groupJson = apiGroup.generateCreateGroupJsonObject(groupName_rename);
      const apicategory = await api.postTeamCategoriesWithCategoryID(categoryID,renameCategoryJson);

      //const apicategory = await api.postTeamCategoriesWithCategoryID(categoryID,categoryrenameJson);
      expect(apicategory).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Rename category successfully executed");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        console.log("Failed to Rename category");
        throw e;
      }
  });

  //Delete Category API
  test.skip('Delete Category API', async()=> {
    jest.setTimeout(20000);
    try {
      console.log("Delete Created Cateory");
      console.log("Running delete category and attemptin to delete ::: " + categoryID);
      const apicategory = await api.deleteTeamCategoriesWithCategoryID(categoryID);
      expect(apicategory).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Delete category successfully executed");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      console.log("Failed to delete category");
      throw e;
    }
  });

});
```

Separate Json Functions for `teamCategory.js` File name `ApiCategory.js`

```
class ApiCategory {

  constructor()
  {
    //super();
  }

 generateCreateCategoryJsonObject(categoryName,groupID)  {

    return{
                  "name": categoryName,
                  "groupId": groupID,     //if you pass manually groupId here and run the code then code is executed successfully.
                  "parent": 0

          }
    }

renameCreateCategoryJsonObject(categoryName_rename) {

    return{
      "name": categoryName_rename
    }

}

} 
module.exports = ApiCategory;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is getting resolve after add this lines to `teamgroupapi.js` file

```
export let groupID;
exports.groupID = groupID;
```

After add above two lines in `teamgroupapi.js` file.

```
import { getGeneratedApi } from '@test/bender-executor-simple-api-generator';
import ApiGroup from '../_support/ApiGroup.js';

const request = require('supertest');
const fs = require('fs');
const assert = require('assert')
const chakram = require ('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;

const swaggerPath = process.env.BENDER_SWAGGER_PATH || 'https://api-slurmhourly.hourly.cc.altus.bblabs/documentation/api.yaml';
const token = process.env.BENDER_LOGIN_TOKEN || 'ju7WkQItxRMFdMtghlGEVz5CZdC1b4umwLId16591CbK00hWs1a1_lT63cBr8xkvBhPK_vWO-fJTUBdP99LFVw';
console.log(`login token is ${token}`);
const apiUrl = 'https://' + (process.env.CC_URL_API || 'api-slurmhourly.hourly.cc.altus.bblabs');

const readJsonTestFile = (testfilename) =>  {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testfilename, 'utf8'));
};

export var groupID;

describe('Create Group all api generated', () => {

  let api;
  let apiGroup;
  //let groupID;
  const groupName = "Test_" + new Date().getTime();
  const groupName_rename = "Rename_" + new Date().getTime();

  //const groupJson = { "name": groupName };
  //const grouprenameJson = { "name": groupName_rename };

  beforeAll(async () => {
      api = await getGeneratedApi(apiUrl, token, swaggerPath);
      console.log(api);
      apiGroup = new ApiGroup();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
   //  TODO setup.cleanupDb();
   //  await setup.gateway();
  });
  //Create Group API
  test('Create Group', async() => {
    try
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Create Group");
      const groupJson = apiGroup.generateCreateGroupJsonObject(groupName);
      const createGroup = await api.postTeamGroups(groupJson);
      expect(createGroup).to.have.status(201);
      console.log("Create group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to create group");
      throw e;
    }
  });
  //Get Group API
  test('Get Group API', async() => {
    try
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Get Created Group");
      let foundIndex = -1;
      console.log("Running get group and attempting to get ::: " + groupName);
      const getGroup = await api.getTeamGroups(false,false);
      expect(getGroup).to.have.status(200);
        for(var i = 0; i < getGroup.body.length;i++){
            if((getGroup.body[i].name == groupName) && (getGroup.body[i].id != '') ) {
                 foundIndex = i;
                 break;
             }
        }
      groupID = getGroup.body[i].id;
      console.log("Group ID ---->>>>" + getGroup.body[i].id);
      console.log("Group Name ---->>>>" + getGroup.body[i].name);
      expect(foundIndex).to.be.above(-1);
      console.log("Get group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to get group");
      throw e;     
    }
  });
  // Rename Group API
    test.skip('Rename Group API with Group ID', async()=> {
    try 
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Rename already created group");
      const groupJson = apiGroup.generateCreateGroupJsonObject(groupName_rename);
      const apigroup = await api.postTeamGroupsWithGroupID(groupID,groupJson);
      expect(apigroup).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Rename group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to rename group");
      throw e;     
    }
  });
  //Delete Group API
  test.skip('Delete Group API', async()=> {
    try 
    {
      jest.setTimeout(10000);
      console.log("Delete Created Group");
      console.log("Running delete group and attemptin to delete ::: " + groupID);

      const apigroup = await api.deleteTeamGroupsWithGroupID(groupID);

      expect(apigroup).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Delete group successfully executed");
    } catch(e){
      console.log("Failed to delete group");
      throw e;     
    }
  });
});
exports.groupID = groupID;
```

In `teamCategoryApi.js` file add this two lines.

```
var teamgroupapi = require('./teamgroupapi.js');
groupID = teamgroupapi.groupID;
```

After Add above two lines in `teamCategoryApi.js` file issue is getting resolved.

```
import { getGeneratedApi } from '@test/bender-executor-simple-api-generator';
import ApiCategory from '../_support/ApiCategory.js';
var teamgroupapi = require('./teamgroupapi.js');

const request = require('supertest');
const fs = require('fs');
const assert = require('assert')
const chakram = require ('chakram');
const expect = chakram.expect;

const swaggerPath = process.env.BENDER_SWAGGER_PATH || 'https://api-slurmhourly.hourly.cc.altus.bblabs/documentation/api.json';
const token = process.env.BENDER_LOGIN_TOKEN || 'ju7WkQItxRMFdMtghlGEVz5CZdC1b4umwLId16591CbK00hWs1a1_lT63cBr8xkvBhPK_vWO-fJTUBdP99LFVw';
console.log(`login token is ${token}`);
const apiUrl = 'https://' + (process.env.CC_URL_API || 'api-slurmhourly.hourly.cc.altus.bblabs');

const readJsonTestFile = (testfilename) =>  {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testfilename, 'utf8'));
};

describe('Create category all api generated', () => {

  let api;
  let categoryID;
  let apiCategory;
  let groupID;
  //let teamGroup;
  const categoryName = "Test_" + new Date().getTime();
  const categoryName_rename = "Rename_" + new Date().getTime();
  //const categoryrenameJson = { "name": categoryName_rename };

  beforeAll(async () => {
      api = await getGeneratedApi(apiUrl, token, swaggerPath);
      console.log(api);
      apiCategory = new ApiCategory();
      //teamGroup = new teamgroupapi();
      //console.log(api);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
   //   TODO setup.cleanupDb();
   //   await setup.gateway();
  });

  //Create Category API
  test('Create Category', async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(20000);
    try {
      console.log("Create Category");
      groupID = teamgroupapi.groupID;

      const categoryJson = apiCategory.generateCreateCategoryJsonObject(categoryName,groupID);
      //const categoryJson = { "name": categoryName, "groupId": groupID, "parent": 0 };
      const createCategory = await api.postTeamCategories(categoryJson);
      //const listofCategories = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createCategory));
      //expect(result.response.statusCode).toBe(201);
      expect(createCategory).to.have.status(201);
      console.log("Create category successfully executed");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      console.log("Failed to create category");
      throw e;
    }
  });

  //Get Category API
  test('Get Category API', async() => {
    jest.setTimeout(20000);
    try {
      console.log("Get Created Category");
      let foundIndex = -1;
      //const categoryName = "Test_" + new Date().getTime();
      console.log("Running get category and attempting to get ::: " + categoryName);
      //Check if previously created Group exists using the GET Group API
      //Check the response payload and loop through the response to find the workspace that was created earlier
            //let api = teamGroupApi.api;

      const getCategory = await api.getTeamCategories();
      //const listofCategories = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(apicategory));
      //console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
      //console.log("list of category" + apicategory.body.length);
      expect(getCategory).to.have.status(200);
        for(var i = 0; i < getCategory.body.length;i++){
            if((getCategory.body[i].name == categoryName) && (getCategory.body[i].id != '') ) {
                 foundIndex = i;
                 break;
             }
        }
      categoryID = getCategory.body[i].id;
      console.log("Category Name ---->>>>" + getCategory.body[i].id);
      console.log("Category Name ---->>>>" + getCategory.body[i].name);
      expect(foundIndex).to.be.above(-1);
      console.log("Get Category successfully executed");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      console.log("Failed to get category");
      throw e;
    }
  });

  //Rename Category API
  test('Rename Category API with categoryID', async()=> {
      jest.setTimeout(20000);
      try {
      console.log("Rename already created category");

      const renameCategoryJson = apiCategory.renameCreateCategoryJsonObject(categoryName_rename);

      //const groupJson = apiGroup.generateCreateGroupJsonObject(groupName_rename);
      const apicategory = await api.postTeamCategoriesWithCategoryID(categoryID,renameCategoryJson);

      //const apicategory = await api.postTeamCategoriesWithCategoryID(categoryID,categoryrenameJson);
      expect(apicategory).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Rename category successfully executed");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        console.log("Failed to Rename category");
        throw e;
      }
  });

  //Delete Category API
  test('Delete Category API', async()=> {
    jest.setTimeout(20000);
    try {
      console.log("Delete Created Cateory");
      console.log("Running delete category and attemptin to delete ::: " + categoryID);
      const apicategory = await api.deleteTeamCategoriesWithCategoryID(categoryID);
      expect(apicategory).to.have.status(200);
      console.log("Delete category successfully executed");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      console.log("Failed to delete category");
      throw e;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple pub sub module might help you here

```
const topics = {};
const hOP = topics.hasOwnProperty;

export default class Events {
/**
 *
 * @param topic
 * @param listener
 * @returns {{remove: remove}}
 */
subscribe(topic, listener) {
    if (!hOP.call(topics, topic)) topics[topic] = [];
    const index = topics[topic].push(listener) - 1;

    return {
        remove: function() {
            delete topics[topic][index];
        }
    };
}

/**
 *
 * @param topic
 * @param info
 */
publish(topic, info) {
    if (!hOP.call(topics, topic)) return;

    topics[topic].forEach(function(item) {
        item(info != undefined ? info : {});
    });
}
```

}

Create this in a js file somewhere. then import it into each of your js files. When you want to pass the value from one script to another you can first publish in the teamgroupapi file and subscribe to the event in the teamCategoryApi file.

```
self.events.publish('/eventId', groupId);

events.subscribe('/eventId', (groupId) => {
    console.log(groupId);
            // do stuff
        });
```

Comment: The example provided gives you a nice way to pass variables between javascript files and a way to alert each file if a variable was updated, you will need to fit the example code into your application and modify it as it applies to your project. Since we are dealing with multiple files there is no way I could provide a working example. The first chunk is a pub sub module which you can take as is. the second chunk of code you need to fit into your script as required.

Comment: no worries, I see you went with exporting the var instead, also a perfectly fine solution :)